# How to push my CI generated apk/ipa files into MobileIron as part of my Jenkins Job?

Tags: jenkins, mdm, mobileiron

How to push the IPA/APK files generated out of my Jenkins CI job into Mobile Iron managed devices automatically?

Thanks,
Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of MobileIron Core (7.5.1) provides all web services to fulfill your requirement, such as upload an app to MobileIron app store, add it to a label and so on.
For details you have to consult MobileIron API Reference documentation.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jago, Do we have any open source MDM/MAM which can perform all these functionalities like mobile iron?

Comment: Hi Ravi, due to the nature of MDM a device can only be managed through one system. If you have already deployed MobileIron you can't add such functionality with an add-on product. If MobileIron is only an alternative you can also deal with another MDM solution. Asking Google I found for example wso2.com [Link](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/) as an open source MDM solution, which also provides a web service interface to publish apps automatically. But I'm sorry, I don't have any expirience with that solution.